# How to modify and save a column in the sqlite3 database using python?

Tags: python, sqlite

Sorry guys, this is the second post for this question, it was my mistake I did not clarify the question in the previous post.
I have a CSV file  (A.csv) has many columns. The question is how to modify and save a column in this file. I would like to replace the value 1 in column y based on the previous value.

```
A = [ d   x    y    z
  0   1    2    5
  1   2    1    9
  2   8    1    2
  3   3    40   7
  4   6    1    7
  5   4    30   3
  6   8    40   8
  7   9    1   10
  8   6    1    4
  9  10   10    7]
```

The expected answer should be :

```
A = [ d   x    y    z
  0   1    2    5
  1   2    2    9
  2   8    2    2
  3   3    40   7
  4   6    40   7
  5   4    30   3
  6   8    40   8
  7   9    40   10
  8   6    40   4
  9  10    10   7]
```

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import numpy
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
conn.text_factory = str 
cur = conn.cursor()
A = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")


with open('output_data1001.csv', 'w') as f: 
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(['d', 'x','y','z'])
  writer.writerows(A)
```

I am really sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Do you want these changes to actually persist in the database, or do you want to just do this in your Python script?

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reply. I want it in both

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do this update directly in SQLite:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET y = (SELECT t2.y
         FROM yourTable t2
         WHERE t2.d < t1.d AND t2.y <> 1
         ORDER BY t2.d DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE y = 1;
```

In plain English, the above update targets all rows where `y = 1`.  For such rows, it seeks backwards, to records having lesser values of `d`, and finds the latest record where `y` is not equal to 1.  It then updates using this value.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I have only one table in my Database

Comment: Good.  My query only refers to your single table :-)

Comment: So, what about "FROM yourTable t2" in your query?  what is t2 stand for?

Comment: `t2` is an alias, which lets us distinguish between the two calls to your single table.

Comment: Please Tim correct me if I am wrong, The code is not working: value is the column i want to change on it.                                        data = cur.execute('UPDATE data t1 SET value = (SELECT t2.y FROM data t2 WHERE t2.d < t1.d AND t2.y <> 1 ORDER BY t2.d DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE value = 1')

Comment: Sorry guys for bothering you, but I really want your help. I applied this code but it didnt work. Any help!!!                                                                                                data = cur.execute('UPDATE CH2_data t1 SET CH1 = (SELECT t2.CH1 FROM CH2_data t2 WHERE t2.No. < t1.No. AND t2.CH1 <> 1 ORDER BY t2.No. DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE CH1 = ""')

conn.commit()